# Postgresql psql how to print select result to command line, instead of editor

Tags: postgresql

When I use \d command, psql displays tables for me on the current screen. Then I can input my next command on the same screen.

But, select is different. Issue the command: select * from mytable, psql displays the result on another screen. I have to press q to quit it and return to command line screen.

I want to select command to display the result on the same screen in command line. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more? trying to understand your problem, what's the printing difference between \d and `select`?

Comment: Is there anything weird in your `.psqlrc` file?

Comment: Are you talking about the pager, rather than the editor?  You can `\pset pager off` if you want the results sent to a pager, like "more" or "less".

Comment: Thanks, I changed the description to make it clearer. Sorry for the confusing.

Comment: @jjanes You should answer with that "\pset pager off detail", I think that is the correct answer